# Proper use of checker for an applicative

Tags: haskell

I have the following applicative implementation (is the classic Validation)

```
module Validation where

import           Test.QuickCheck          (Arbitrary (arbitrary), frequency)
import           Test.QuickCheck.Checkers (EqProp ((=-=)), eq, quickBatch)
import           Test.QuickCheck.Classes  (applicative)

data Validation e a =
    Failure e
    | Success a
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (Validation e) where
    fmap f (Success a) = Success (f a)
    fmap _ (Failure e) = Failure e

instance (Arbitrary e, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Validation e a) where
  arbitrary = do
      e <- arbitrary
      b <- arbitrary
      frequency [(1, return (Failure e))
                , (1, return (Success b))]

instance (Eq e, Eq a) => EqProp (Validation e a) where
    (=-=) = eq

instance Monoid e => Applicative (Validation e) where
    pure = Success
    (<*>) (Success f) (Success x) = Success (f x)
    (<*>) (Success _) (Failure y) = Failure y
    (<*>) (Failure x) (Success _) = Failure x
    (<*>) (Failure x) (Failure y) = Failure (x <> y)
```

Trying to check the applicative implementation with checkers

My try so far

```
type ValidationTyped = (Validation String Int)
trigger :: ValidationTyped
trigger = undefined

main :: IO ()
main = do
    quickBatch $ applicative trigger
```

But this does not work as it won't compile, any suggestions?

Edit:

Error message

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘(a0, b0, c0)’
  Expected type: Validation String (a0, b0, c0)
    Actual type: ValidationTyped
• In the first argument of ‘applicative’, namely ‘trigger’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘applicative trigger’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: quickBatch $ applicative
```

Comment: you are looking for this: `  quickBatch $ applicative (undefined :: Validation String (String, String, String))` in your `man`, I think.

Comment: @user1984 You are right, I replaced `type ValidationTyped = (Validation String (String, String, Int))` and it worked, please detail in an answer why so I can mark accordingly.

Comment: Your `Arbitrary` instance seems to do a bit more work than necessary, producing random things that it ends up throwing away. It's also more complicated than it needs to be. I suggest `arbitrary = frequency [(1, Failure <$> arbitrary), (1, Success <$> arbitrary)]`.

Comment: @dfeuer I understand the complicated part and how it can be simplified but I don't understand what you mean by `producing things tat it ends up throwing away`

Comment: @calin, yours has to generate a random number to produce `e` and another to produce `b`, though you're only going to use one of them. Better to decide which first and then generate just that one.